# libpq-fe, can't select an INT8

Tags: c, postgresql, select

I program with C, there i use the library [libpq-dev/libpq-fe](http://packages.debian.org/de/squeeze/libpq-dev). With this library i connect to a local postgresql-Database.

I wrote some test-code, which selects/inserts something. But i had always one problem:
I only can select [INT4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype.html#DATATYPE-INT) (4 Byte Int) numerical values or strings. May be others to, i didnt tried every type. But i can't select INT8-values (8 Byte Int).

Examples:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*)::INT8 FROM tb_Test;"
```

This gives me an INT8 as result. I dont' know how i can get it? I tried this:

```
long count = ntohl(*(uint64_t*)PQgetvalue(result, 0, 0));
```

Count is always 0.
But if i execute this select, which contains an explicit type-cast, it works:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*)::INT4 FROM tb_Test;"
```

I use this code to get the count:

```
long count = ntohl(*(uint32_t*)PQgetvalue(result, 0, 0));
```

Does anyone know what's the problem? If you like that i post more code please say it. I only posted this, because i think this is the only relevant part.

Thanks

Comment: This may have something to do with `ntohl`, which operates on `long`. `long` may or may not be the same as `uint64_t`. For `uint64_t`, use `le64toh`.

Comment: This gives the same result. The resulting value is always 0. I tried `long` instead of `uint64_t`, but this didn't work too.

Answer (score 1):

The return values of `PQgetvalue()` are strings.  You could then use something like `strtoll()` to convert them to an integer type.